# Angular - How to filter a dynamic data?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two different types of interfaces, I want to filter the data based on the given interface which will be provided dynamically.

```
export interface Country {
    cId: string;
    cName: string;
    cFlag: string;
}

export interface Address {
    aId: string;
    aName: string;
    aStreet: string;
}
```

I've created a method where it filters data of a single type of interface, I want this method to filter any data of any type, here is the code:

```
public data: any[] = [];

var filteredObject = this.data;
var { search } = query;

if (search) {
    search = search.toLowerCase();
    filteredObject = filteredObject.filter((f) => {
    f.includes(search);
    ({ firstColumn, secondColumn, thirdColumn }) =>
        firstColumn.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
        secondColumn.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
        thirdColumn.toLowerCase().includes(search)
    });
}
```

As you can see, first, second and third columns of filter should be dynamic and depending on type of the passed interface, for instance:

if type of interface is **Country** then `cId, cName, cFlag` must be instead of static values, and so on.

Comment: You can filter object values according to their type, if they are string or not, then filter according to searchvalue.

Comment: Then I must provide a keys list of the passed interface??

Comment: If you use object.values on your object it will become field agnostic, unless you want specify certain fields of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @berk-kurkcuoglu said you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) in `filter`. With [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and `toString` you can filter any type of field except object type fields.

```js
const data: any[] = [
  { cId: 1, cName: "Peru", cFlag: 2 },
  { aId: 1, cName: "work", cStreet: "93 Mcguire Plaza" },
];

let filteredObject = data;
let search = "pe";

if (search) {
  search = search.toLowerCase();
  filteredObject = filteredObject.filter((f) => {
    return Object.values(f).some(v => {
      // if (typeof v !== "string") return false;
      return v?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search);
    });
  });
}

console.log(filteredObject);
```

Comment: I've already solved the problem as @berk-kurkcuoglu mentioned :). By the way, his comment and your answer also accepted)